# Eu preciso fechar um InputStream?

Tags: java, stream, inputstream

Eu tenho o seguinte.

```
InputStream in = (InputStream) response.getEntity();
```

Eu preciso fechar? Sendo que o `close()` do `inputStream` não faz nada?

Comment: `InputStream` é uma classe abstrata. Quer dizer que na prática você sempre está usando alguma sub-classe dela, que pode ou não sobrescrever o método `close`. O fato de você ter criado uma variável do tipo `InputStream` não quer dizer necessariamente que ao chamar `close` estará chamando a versão que não faz nada. Se a sub-classe sobrescrever o método, é este que será chamado. E se a sub-classe foi bem implementada, o `close` fará tudo que for necessário para fechar corretamente o stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos ver a [documentação da classe](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html), que é algo que deve fazer sempre que for usar algo, e parece que o AP fez, fica para os demais.

Aí vemos que ela implementa uma interface chama `AutoCloseable`. Vendo [sua documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) diz que ela tem um método `close()` que deve ser chamado para fechar a classe que a implementa.

Mas ali mesmo também disse que isso pode ser feito de forma automática, como o nome já indica, e isso deve ser feito com o chamado *try-resources*, até para garantir que o fechamento seja chamado mesmo que ocorra um erro.

Então oficialmente deve fechar sim, mas deve fazer de forma segura, da maneira correta:

```
try (InputStream in = (InputStream) response.getEntity()) {
    // faz o que precisa
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/Try.java).

A documentação diz isso. Então deveria fazer. Mas de fato a documentação também diz que esse método faz nada.

Também vemos na documentação que ela é abstrata. Mesmo que não fosse ela não é final, então ela pode ser herdada, nesse caso é até obrigatório que seja. Então as derivações dela podem ter um recurso que precise ser dispensado.

Como é possível que use o tipo `InputStream` em algum lugar mas a implementação concreta do objeto usado seja de um tipo que use o padrão Disposable de forma efetiva, então se você não usar a forma que fecha o recurso de forma garantida poderá ter um vazamento de recurso.

Por isso ou deve usar o tipo mais concreto, final,  que você sabe que também tem nada no `close()` e que nunca mudará, ou então deve usar o `try` para garantir a dispensa.

Se você quiser confiar que só será usado em objetos que continuam com o comportamento de fazer nada no fechamento, então ok, mas é um risco que terá que assumir. Usar o `try` e ele ser um desperdício, ou não usar e no futuro, improvável, mudar e você ter que revisar todos códigos que fez para arrumar. Não é uma decisão simples.

Se trabalha em equipe deve ser combinado com todos para ser consistente.

Tem o lado mais "seguro" ou mais performático. Em quase todas situações, porque tudo deve ter um contexto e exceção do que fazer, eu iria pelo lado seguro, se tem o negócio ali então use. E se não usar documente muito bem fora do código para saber que um dia pode ter que mudar, e só faça isso se precisar de máxima eficiência e puder garantir que não virá algo que o fechamento será imprescindível.

Eu dei uma pesquisada e há controvérsias sobre o fechamento ou não. Inclusive tem códigos bem conhecidos que fecham e outros que não fecham. Acho que todos ignoraram a questão da herança levantada pelo hkotsubo e o wldomiciano.

O contexto de onde é usado também conta. Em uma aplicação que executa por bem pouco tempo até mesmo recursos que deveriam ser fechados por necessidade real não precisam porque a aplicação morre logo em seguida. Isso é ser pragmático.

Curioso como você se deu ao trabalho de ler toda documentação. Todas respostas sobre o assunto que li por aí ignoraram essa questão do método fazer nada.

Comment: Tenho uma observação, me diga se faz sentido: Apesar da doc de `InputStream` estabelecer que o método faz nada, temos que ter em mente que ela é uma classe abstrata, logo, sempre que temos objetos deste tipo, na verdade estamos lidando com instâncias de classes concretas que a extendem. Por isso, apesar das controvérisias que vc mencionou, eu acho que tem que fechar sempre. Veja uma a [`FileInputStream`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-17%2B35/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/FileInputStream.java#L439) por exemplo, ela faz coisas no `close()`.

Comment: @wldomiciano sim, vou dar uma mexida sobre isso.